# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[250, 64, 4, 4, 4] to have 1 channels, but got 64 channels instead

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

This is the architecture based on a research paper.

```
class NBV_Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dropout_prob):

        super(NBV_Net, self).__init__()
        
        #dropout_prob = 0.0 # 1 - 0.7

        # Four 3D convolutional layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(1,16, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride = (2,2,2))       

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(16, 32, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride = (2,2,2))
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv3_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(2,2,2), stride = (2,2,2))    

        self.conv4 = nn.Conv3d(64, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv4_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)
         

        # Five fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4096, 1500)   
        self.fc1_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)

        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1500, 500)
        self.fc2_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)      

        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(500, 100)
        self.fc3_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)      

        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(100, 50)
        self.fc4_drop = nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)   
        
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(50, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        ## feedforward behavior of NBV-net
        x = self.pool1(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))

        x = self.pool2(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))

        x = self.pool3(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))

        x = self(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))

        # Aplanar
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
               
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc1_drop(x)      

        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc2_drop(x)       

        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc3_drop(x)       

        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x)) 
        x = self.fc4_drop(x)
        
        x = F.tanh(self.fc5(x)) 
        
        return x
```

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 1, 3, 3, 3], expected input[250, 64, 4, 4, 4] to have 1 channels, but got 64 channels instead

But this code gives the Runtime Error. Similar errors are there but I could not understand what Group 1 and other dimensions mentioned exactly mean , any idea about the background of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The input shape for `nn.Conv3d(1,16, 3, stride=1, padding=1)` is `(batch, channels, depth, height, width)`.

You define that the channel size is `1` but your input tensor has 64 channels.

`self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(64,16, 3, stride=1, padding=1)` will resolve you error

Comment: I got this error when changed the channel size to 16. RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 64, 3, 3, 3], expected input[250, 1, 32, 32, 32] to have 64 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Comment: what is the shape of your input tensor?

Comment: 32*32*32 is the shape of my input tensor

Comment: your input tensor to a conv3d should have the following shape `(batch, channels, depth, height, width)`